# Deleting cell from table - Code provided

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a `tableviewController`. On the `UINavigationBar` i will be adding a button called Edit. When the user clicks on it i need all the cells to go for the edit mode, where they could delete records.

I guess the following method does it. Am i correct ? will i get the red circle and the delete button on the cell when i click the edit button?

2.) How can i write the code for the Edit button (`UIBarbuttonitem`), when the user clicks it to call the following method ?

3.) When we delete the cell, i need to reload the data in the table. I wrote the code for this, is it correct. (I am not in my Mac at the moment)

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        [discardedItems addObject:[self.entries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [self.itemsMutableArray removeObjectsInArray:discardedItems ]; 
        self.entries = [NSArray arrayWithArray:self.itemsMutableArray];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];

        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
```

Comment: what do you use the itemsMutableArray for? Can't you just have entries as an mutable array?

Comment: I copied the content of `entries` array to it, so i could easily remove items and then reassign it to the `entries` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to specify if the rows can be edited. This is done by the following method

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

return yes if you want all the rows to be editable.

To get the red circles use this,

Perhaps in a method called by the edit button...

```
UIBarButtonItem *editButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Edit ", @"") style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(pressedEdit:)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editButton;
```

(in viewdidload)

and in pressedEdit:

```
- (void) pressedEdit :(id)sender {
    UIBarButtonItem *editButton = (UIBarButtonItem*)self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem;

    if (!self.tabeView.editing) {
        [self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
        editButton.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Done", @"");
    }
    else {
        [self.tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];
        editButton.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Edit", @"");
    }
}
```

According to the code youve written, i think you should first update the datasource and then remove the cell...

Comment: Where should i write the `[self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];` ? is it inside the `viewdidLoad` method ? Should i include `        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
` inside `[self.tableView beginUpdates];
` ??

Comment: deleteRowsAtIndexPaths should be after deleting from data array.
setEditing: should be called when you want the red circles to appear.
I also don't think beginUpdates and endUpdates is necessary

Comment: When creating the UIBarbuttonItem what should i add to the `Action` attribute ? (which method should it execute) ?

Comment: When i click the Edit button it'll go into the edit state, Then i should change the title of the button to `done` and when the user clicks on that i should say `[self.tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES]; ? Am i correct ?
`

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not seem wrong. But so many lines for so little work. You kill the animation with reloadData too. And you wrap calls that do not even touch the tableView in beginUpdates/endUpdates.

Why not use a NSMutableArray as datasource in the first place? You can reduce seven lines of code turned to two:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // delete the item from the datasource
        [self.entries removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        // Delete the row from the table view
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
```

Comment: perhaps he wants to keep track of the deleted items in the discardedItems array. But I completely agree with you...

Comment: Yes, i need to keep track of the deleted records. But i still want to know how will the code know if i have clicked the `edit` uibarbutton to add execute the above methods ?